# Studying continuity on multivariable functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

I am given a few functions and I have to study the following aspects:

- Continuity in the point (0,0)
- If the derivative exists at (0,0)
- Continuity of the partial derivatives at (0,0)
- Directional derivatives at (0,0)

One of the functions is, for example:
$$  f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{x^2y^2}{\sqrt(x^2+y^2)},  & \text{if if (x,y) not (0,0)} \\
0, & \text{if (x,y) = (0,0)}
\end{cases}$$

I was able to prove the continuity of the function via epsilon-delta proof (proved the $\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y) = 0$), but my question is: do I always have to do this to prove the continuity of a function? So I have to do the same for the continuity of the partial derivatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the polar coordinates transformation: $\begin{cases}x &=& r\cos\theta \\ y &=& r\sin\theta\end{cases}$

Then, $f(x,y) = r^3\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta$

Now, since $\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta$ is bounded, one can use the squeeze theorem.

Comment: That is a cool way to prove it, but is it the only way (along with epsilon delta) to prove the continuity?